# Beam too close to ceiling for fixture

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to replace a light fixture. The problem is that the beam holding the previous fixture is too low and the new fixture's wires go through the nipple. If the crossbar is screwed on to the beam, there is not enough space for the nipple to go through the crossbar while leaving room for the wires to come out. I don't know if there are any 'standard' solutions to this sort of problem, but I can't think of anything short of of sawing off part of the nipple (without hitting the wires somehow!).

[image: ]]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the small diameter nipple screws into the shorter, larger diameter 'nipple', and the second nut is acting as a locknut. Once the locknut is loosened, the inner nipple ought to unscrew with finger pressure from inside the larger, shorter threaded 'nipple'.

Once the locknut is off, you might be able to screw in the nipple deeper. Or you could cut it off without risking damaging the wires, or you could replace it with a shorter nipple (available at local hardware store, Home Depot, Lowes, etc)

Comment: Shouldn't a down vote have some explanation?

Comment: A shortened nipple crossed my mind too, but where are you proposing the wires go after that?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: being able to pull the inner nipple from the outer one makes the whole thing a bit easier to deal with. Are there replacement nipples that have a whole for wires to come out of? If not, I might try a hickey like ThreePhaseEel suggests in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### Get a stud and hickey

Your fixture, with the wires threaded through the nipple, is designed to be mounted using a part called a *hickey* (don't ask me about the name!) that looks like this:

[image: fixture hickey]

and attaches to a threaded stud that screws into the hole in the middle of your pancake box.

So, thread an appropriately sized fixture-stud into the pancake box, thread a hickey onto the stud, and then thread the fixture nipple onto the hickey.  Now, you'll be able to get the wires to go where they need to.

Comment: Good suggestion. I think once I replace the original nipple with something much shorter I might be able to use a hickey as you suggest. I worry even then there won't be enough space, but I'll stop by the store this week and see what they have.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is a sort of pancake box with a threaded hole in the center for this nipple. I have never seen this sort of box. Is this a code approved box? Is meant to be installed as a transition piece over a standard deep ceiling box? It could be that it is not intended to be installed directly to the structural member, especially to wood.

Comment: That's a saddle box, not a pancake box...

Comment: Oh, I see now. So it is meant to go over 2x lumber on edge rather than on the side like this 2x4. Could this 2x4 have a hole drilled all the way through to allow the nipple to protrude? It is presumably not structural could it be cut or drilled to accommodate this saddle box?